# Is there a way to create Matrices in R that use less memory than standard matrices?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, memory

On my machine,

```
m1 = ( runif(5*10^7), ncol=10000, nrow=5000 )
```

uses up about 380 MB. I need to work with many of such matrices at the same time in memory (e.g. add or multiply them or `apply` functions on them). All in all my code uses up 4 GB of RAM due to multiple matrices stored in memory. I am contemplating options to store the data more efficiently (i.e. in a way that uses up less RAM).

I have seen the `R` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) `bigmemory` being recommended. However:

```
library(bigmemory)
m2 = big.matrix( init = 0, ncol=10000, nrow=5000 )
m2[1:5000,1:10000] <- runif( 5*10^7 )
```

makes R use about the same amount in memory as I verified using Windows Task Manager. So I anticipate no big gain, or am I wrong and should I use `big.matrix` in a different way?

Comment: not sure whether it will suit your needs, but package e1071 has sparse matrix functionality

Comment: In your second code chunk, `runif(5*10^7)` is what eats up your memory, so assigning it to a big.matrix won't help. Think on how you want to initialise your matrix.

Comment: @Hong Ooi it's not clear whether the OP is using that to initialize the matrix. They may just be using it as an example of the sort of data they're working with. If this is indeed representative, sparse matrices aren't appropriate. The OP is either going to have to deal with a lot of memory being used, or rewrite the code to use the hard drive.

Comment: @Acccumulation Indeed I am concerned with the problem of a matrix of the indicated size filled with float numbers. Wouldn't hard drive usage hamper performance more than having it in RAM and pagefile?

Comment: If you're doing a lot of drive reads, that will be slower than RAM, but pagefile is just an interface for the hard drive. It's designed to reduce seek times compared to normal hard drive access, but I don't think that's relevant if you have a SSD. You can time your code and see how much difference there is in keeping things in memory versus doing drive swaps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to work with matrices stored in files, i.e. setting `backingfile` to not `NULL` in the call of `big.matrix()` function.

Comment: Will this hamper performance less than using `matrix` in RAM + pagefile?

Comment: Yes. In my experience, it's even better to use my package `filematrix` for this, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Working with filebacked `big.matrix` from package **bigmemory** is a good solution.

However, assigning the whole matrix with `runif( 5*10^7 )` makes you create this large temporary vector in memory. Yet, if you use `gc(reset = TRUE)`, you will see that this memory usage disappear.

If you want to initialize your matrix by block (say blocks of 500 columns), you could use package **bigstatsr**. It uses similar objects as filebacked `big.matrix` (called `FBM`) and store them in your temporary directory by default. You could do:

```
library(bigstatsr)

m1 <- FBM(1e4, 5e3)

big_apply(m1, a.FUN = function(X, ind) {
  X[, ind] <- runif(nrow(X) * length(ind))
  NULL
}, a.combine = 'c', block.size = 500)
```

Comment: The help file of `big.matrix` indicates that performance may be hampered by using the file backend. Is it still more efficient to use the file backend than using `matrix` in RAM + pagefile (the latter for excess memory)?

Comment: @tomka If for "pagefile" you're referring to swapping, this is the worst that can happen to you. Of course, if you have enough memory, using standard R matrices will be the fastest. But I think Filebacked Big Matrices are a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the makeup of your dataset, a [sparse.matrix](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/) could be your best way forward. This is a common and extremely useful way to boost space and time efficiency. In fact, a lot of R packages require that you use sparse matrices.

Comment: Unfortunately, my data is not sparse, I believe. The matrix is filled with floats.